# How to set the precision of a FLOAT in BigQuery schema

Tags: google-bigquery, floating-point

In BigQuery, if I want to round a `FLOAT` type field in a query I use the `ROUND()` function.
Is it possible to set the precision in the schema or through some option/parameter?

Example :

A data file contains some `FLOAT` type fields that contain too many digits after the decimal point (18), I want to round it up during the upload process, by specifying some parameter or option within the schema.

```
[
 {"mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "BRAND", "type": "STRING", "description": null},
 {"mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "PRICE", "type": "FLOAT", "description": null [, "<precision>":"2"]}
]
```

Comment: No unfortunately that's not possible on the schema definition level, what you might look at is to define a new udf who could be triggered when uploading a new file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No data transformation can be performed when you upload data into BigQuery.

In general you can try some other methods :

Create a new table from uploaded table. For this you can create a query and can perform required transformation in it.
eg: CREATE TABLE project_name.dataset_name.new_table_name as SELECT Brand, round(price,5) as Price from project_name.dataset_name.uploaded_table_name;

Creating a table from a query result. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_a_table_from_a_query_result